# Do non-ACM events/conferences publish & index their final proceedings in the ACM digital library?

Tags: publications, peer-review, acm

I am looking into options to submit my research paper to this conference:
- http://www.icbdr.org/ or - http://www.iccbdc.org/index.html

Both of the links indicate that after acceptance, the paper will be published in ACM library and indexed in Scopus and EI. But after I discussed with my colleagues they said that there is a chance of being a scam.

I checked the ACM main events but did not find any of the above-mentioned conferences but instead, I found them in Non-ACM Events http://www.acm.org/conferences/non-acm-events.

Does it mean that the work will be published and archived in ACM library?

**UPDATE:** I contacted the Elsevier Ehelpdesk and got the following reply:

> Dear xxxxxx, Thank you for reaching Elsevier Ehelpdesk regarding
>   Scopus Indexing.   The 2017 International Conference on Cloud and Big
>   Data Computing (ICCBDC 2017) is set to be published under the
>   International Conference Proceedings Series by  ACM as seen on their
>   site http://www.iccbdc.org/index.html.   I can confirm that the
>   International Conference Proceedings Series by  ACM is already indexed
>   in Scopus which has several conference titles already indexed.   Once
>   a conference is is published, the publisher will be processing the
>   title to be included in Scopus to be indexed.   I hope I have provided
>   you with everything you need. Should you have further query, please
>   don't hesitate to email me back. Kind regards,

Comment: I would not submit my work to any of these. This looks like easy business model.

Comment: @Coder i am only considering them because the accepted papers will be indexed in ACM.   Why do I have to care about their business model since my work will be indexed in ACM? In other words, why do I have to submit the work to an IEEE ranked conference and wait for 2 months in order to get feedback ? and most probably in both cases you will be paying the same fees and the reviewers will pass the work to their masters students to check the work up and got the same quality feedback from the less ranked one...

Comment: Links are down. [Link 1: icbdr.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180203085627/http://www.icbdr.org/) // [link 2: iccbdc.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170830100140/http://www.iccbdc.org/index.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, but there are rules.**

There are three ways for conferences to have their proceedings published in the ACM Digital Library.

What most people mean by an "ACM conference" is a conference that is [**sponsored**](https://www.acm.org/special-interest-groups/volunteer-resources/conference-manual/read-me) by ACM or one of its special interest groups.  Proceedings of all ACM-sponsored conferences are published in the ACM Digital Library.  ACM sponsorship must be advertised in all conference publicity, including the conference web site and call for papers.

Conferences can also be held [**in cooperation**](https://www.acm.org/special-interest-groups/volunteer-resources/conference-manual/1-3) with ACM.  In-cooperation conferences can *apply* for their proceedings to be published in the Digital Library, but not all such applications are approved.  Cooperation with ACM must be advertised in all conference publicity, including the conference web site and call for papers.  In particular, in-cooperation conferences *cannot* claim to be sponsored by ACM.

Conferences can also apply to publish their proceedings in [**ACM’s International Conference Proceedings Series**](http://www.acm.org/publications/icps-series) without sponsorship or cooperation.  These conferences are *allowed* to use a special [ACM-ICPS logo](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/gallery/acm/ctas/icps-logo-plain.jpg) on publicity materials to advertise the publication agreement, but they cannot claim to be sponsored by or held in cooperation with ACM.  **This is the agreement advertised by [ICCBDC](http://www.iccbdc.org/index.html).**

Nothing on the [ICBDR web site](http://www.icbdr.org/) suggests that their [proceedings](http://www.icbdr.org/proceedings.html) will be published in the ACM Digital Library, so they almost certainly won't be.

(Indexing is a separate question.  A very small number of proceedings series like [VLDB](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=J1174) are *indexed* in the Digital Library even though they are not *published* by ACM.)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to answer to this question along with a combination of the replied comment provided to my own comment here.

> I am looking into options to submit my research paper to this conference: - http://www.icbdr.org/ or - http://www.iccbdc.org/index.html
>
> Both of the links indicate that after acceptance, the paper will be published in ACM library and indexed in Scopus and EI. But after I discussed with my colleagues they said that there is a chance of being a scam.

I visited the first link, but I could not find a detail in which says that it is going publish the proceeding in ACM.(probably I missed it.) Regarding the latter, it does indicate that in their homepage. It is quite possible that ACM might publish it. Moreover, you should also note that the ACM website might be quite lazy in updating it and the agreement has recently been made.

> I checked the ACM main events but did not find any of the above-mentioned conferences but instead, I found them in Non-ACM Events http://www.acm.org/conferences/non-acm-events.

This could be true if ACM is sponsoring the event in some way. Probably, just by publishing the proceedings. I would suggest checking with ACM or the conference committee first.

> Does it mean that the work will be published and archived in ACM library?

Probably YES. But I would advise checking with the Program Chair or Conference Chair before submission. You would not want an unprecedented mail after the acceptance saying that we never promised such thing.

*Answer to the comments:*

> I would not submit my work to any of these. This looks like easy business model. – Coder
>
> @Coder i am only considering them because the accepted papers will be indexed in ACM. Why do I have to care about their business model since my work will be indexed in ACM? In other words, why do I have to submit the work to an IEEE ranked conference and wait for 2 months in order to get feedback ? and most probably in both cases you will be paying the same fees and the reviewers will pass the work to their masters students to check the work up and got the same quality feedback from the less ranked one... – Krebto

- You must care about the business going on in academic research. Because it is your original hard-work and you don't want your work to be in vain after the publication. Nobody is citing your outcomes and the article, or nobody talking about it.
- Your assumption that the quality of review will be same is wrong. The quality does vary with the quality of the conferences. You always get top quality review and rigor in top quality conferences.

If none of the above points matter to you then go ahead and submit your work to one of these (but, not both).

**Still, I would advise you as well as the people visiting academia.SE to take care of the quality of the conference before submitting their work.**

Comment: Coder, you are very confused!   $500 USD for a conference is very much par for the course, if not on the low side.  And all conferences expect at least one author to register for the conference (note that students pay the discounted rate of $450) and be there to present the paper.  Different conferences have different levels of competitiveness, which is a totally different matter.  But to dismiss the conference because it charges $500?  Please don't say such absurd things.

Comment: @FredDouglis I might be.(mark the *..*) All registrations include: ...and *lunche* and dinner for the Sep 19. ... In a paper with more than one author, all the authors attending the conference *most* complete their registration individually. Such a careless web page would suggest what?

Comment: Suggests to me that someone was inattentive and/or English isn't their first language.  Doesn't mean it's a scam.  Certainly your claim that $500 is unheard of and unreasonable doesn't hold water and can lead people to the wrong idea, and to generalize beyond this conference, no?  I'm not saying this conference is or is not legit (though it appears to be OK at first blush, just sloppy webmastery).  I'm just saying using the cost to justify maligning it unfairly puts down not only this conference but every conference I attend.

Comment: @FredDouglis True. I might be wrong. Anyway, it was my justification which could be refuted with other directional logic. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Sure.  And if you take out the discussion about the cost of the conference being an indication of the scam, I'll remove my negative vote :)   I think the general sense -- be sure of quality before submitting work -- is absolutely valid.  And the idea of a non-ACM conference publishing in the ACM DL is indeed unusual (though probably not unheard of).

Comment: @FredDouglis Thank you very much. Your inputs really helped me in updating my conscience on such a topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60467/discussion-between-fred-douglis-and-coder).